# Customize event registration e-mail

Tags: civievent

I have a custom field for a link for events and want to show it on the Events - Registration Confirmation and Receipt (on-line) message.
I was able to modify some other texts I needed in this template but I'm unsuccessful in adding and using my custom field.
I know it is active because I also have a schedule reminder using this custom field. It's a link and I've checked that it's declared as a link and of course active

[image]

Here is what I added to the source code:

```
Lien visio : {capture assign=visio}{event.custom_146}{/capture}<a href="{$visio}">Link</a>
```

In my inbox the e-mail doesn't show the link but even the text 'Link' doesn't show up!

Have I missed something obvious?

Comment: Does the link itself contain some html chars that maybe breaks the tag? Does it work if you use `{$visio|escape}`?

Comment: good question.usually it's a link to a microsoft teams room. For my test I used a basic URL. I'll test with the escape parameter

Comment: after a deep cache cleaning, it worked without adding the escape parameter. Thanks anyway @Demerit